# Looping back near the beggining using std::vector iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, stdvector

I have an iterator that needs to loop near the beginning of the vector whenever it reaches its end, for the amount it went over the end, like so:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {...}, vec1;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();

for(;vec.size() != 0;){

it += k; //k is a const integer
if(it >= vec.end()){
it -= items.end(); // something like that, but this syntax is obviously invalid
}

vec1.push_back(*it);
it = vec.erase(it);
}
```

So perhaps I increment `vec{1,2,3,4,5}` by 3, it should first remove 3, then 1 and put them in `vec1`, in a sense it loops around by however was left when it reached the end. I tried a bunch of different syntaxes, but there's always a type mismatch error. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: `it = items.begin();` ? But you need to take care of `erase` invalidating `it`

Comment: Whenever you use `erase`, you should *always* use [what it returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase#Return_value).

Comment: wait... "for the amount it went over the end" ? An iterator cannot go over the end of the container. You should rather explain what is the actual aim of your code, because your current approach is flawed

Comment: Instead of `it += k;` perhaps: `it = std::next(vec.begin(), (std::distance(vec.begin(), it) + k) % vec.size());` would do the trick.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant for it to go at the beggining + how much was left before it would've "crossed" the end. If it increments by 3 and its at the n - 2 element, it should go to the first element. If it's at the n - 1 element it should go to the second element in the vector (n is the size of the vector). Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you're correct, I fixed that error.

Comment: yes, after reading your code more carefully I think I understood what you want. What I was trying to say before is that not `it -= items.end();` is your problem but already `it += k;` when that goes beyond the vectors end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XY-solution: I recommend keeping an index instead of an iterator and use the remainder operator.

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; vec.size() != 0;){
    i = (i + k) % vec.size();
    vec1.push_back(vec[i]);
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
}
```

> So perhaps I increment vec{1,2,3,4,5} by 3, it should first remove 3

This doesn't match your attempted code. If you increment iterator to first element by 3 and erase it, then you'd be erasing the element with value 4.

Comment: This works great after some tinkering, k should really be k - 1, otherwise if k  = 3 it skips 3 elements and takes out the 4th instead of skipping 2 and taking out the third, but thats almost nitpicking. Thank you very much!

Comment: @yomag1234 yeah, I wasn't quite sure which order was correct for you exactly. Adjust to your liking.